# Finding which row has been selected in a getmdl-select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to populate a drop down using getmdl-select

```
                var ul = document.getElementById('allocateToUL');

                result.forEach(function (u) {
                    var li = document.createElement('li');
                    var dataVal = document.createAttribute('data-value');
                    var dataSelector = document.createAttribute('data-selector');

                    dataVal.value = u.Id;
                    dataSelector.value = u.Id;

                    li.innerText = u.FriendlyName;
                    li.className = 'mdl-menu__item';
                    li.setAttributeNode(dataVal);
                    li.setAttributeNode(dataSelector);

                    ul.appendChild(li);

                    // note call getmdlSelect.init once item is added
                    getmdlSelect.init('.getmdl-select');

                    componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
                });
```

What I do not seem to be able to do is find out which option is selected here;

I have tried

```
document.getElementsByClassName('mdl-menu').find('li.active')
```

But that just tells me 'find' is not a function although it getElements.... does return list of elements.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to use the jQuery find method, but you are not using a jQuery selector. Try replacing:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('mdl-menu').find('li.active')
```

With:

```
$('.mdl-menu').find('li.active')
```